# How to configure EventBridge Scheduled Rule to trigger my Lambda function dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I need help about a subject. (I'm using AWS)

I'm trying to use live activity of ios in my application. I realize that I have to update live activity variable on server side while application is closed on user phone. --> [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/updating-and-ending-your-live-activity-with-activitykit-push-notifications)

I need that update some variables on live activity of user after than 4 hours of user action. I mean that scenario:

- User make an action on app and an endpoint called.
- After 4 hours, some variable should change on live activity.

I create this solution:

- When user call api, I can create an scheduled event on EventBridge. This event trigger lambda function after 4 hours.
- Lambda function will update live activity

But I can not scheduled event of EventBridge dynamically. While I try to create rule on default eventbus, I can choose Scheduled rule type. But I can set only specific time with cron expression.

Events have not schedule feature. Rules have that feature. So I tried create rule and send event to rule on my api. But I can not set target (lambda func) on code.

I think that I'm missing something and lost way.

Do you have any idea about solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand your question. Could you attach some images or code to understand the issue that you face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my description is bad, I'm sorry for this..

I solved this issue.

**EventBridge** is not suit for my needs, I used **EventBridge-Scheduler** (new/last part of tool)

You can find differences here ([aws document](https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/)):
[image: https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/]

Scheduler part has one-time schedule option, deleted after event trigger option,'time window schedules' and specified for exact date time.

The Scheduler is more suit for my needs.